# Get colormap value matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have an image in matlab that is color coded, using hsv, with clim values ranging from -90 to 90. What I now want to do is convert the rgb image into a matrix with the associated values from the cmap (i.e the cmap labels). Could anyone explain how do do this?

I think I can use the rgb2ind to index back into my colormap and then get the associated label, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're starting with.  First you say color-coded, then hsv, then clim -90 to 90, then rgb matrix.  I'm not sure how to reconcile -90 to 90 with an RGB image that you're trying to convert to indexed.  Why not try rgb2ind, then post if you're not happy with the results?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: You can convert the RGB to grayscale or just choose a single color channel.
Step 2: Use `imagesc` to plot that matrix.
Step 3: Use `colormap` to adjust the colorscale to be from -90 to 90.